# What does "double pump" mean in basketball?

Tags: terminology, basketball

Can anybody explain the meaning of "double-pump" in the following sentence:

> Grant sprinted down the court and had an opportunity to win the game at the buzzer, but Kentucky's swarming defense made him double-pump and his shot missed the mark.

Comment: I disagree with the sentence that Grant "double pumped".  He double clutched, as seen in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8OjudFd2q4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Double Pump](http://www.sportingcharts.com/dictionary/nba/double-pump.aspx):

> - **A technique in basketball that consists of faking a shot by pumping the ball quickly into the air twice, as if shooting.** A single pump may not be enough for superior defenders, and by pumping the ball into the air twice, an offensive player increases the chances of getting the defender in the air and out of position.
> - This move is often used to draw a foul on the defender because once the defender is in the air, the offensive player can shoot "into" the defender, thereby causing a foul.